# Deriving wave equation from energy

Tags: waves, solid-state-physics

I have a one-dimensional chain of identical atoms with mass *m*. There are "springs" between all pairs of atoms. Thus, the elastic energy is

$$
U = \frac{1}{2}\sum_j\sum_{l > 0} K_l (u_j - u_{j+l})^2,
$$

where $K_j$ is spring constant and $u_j$ is the displacement of $j$-th atom. I need to find the equation of motion

$$
m\ddot{u}_j = -\frac{\partial U}{\partial u_j}.
$$

So far I managed to get the following equation

$$
 m\ddot{u}_j = \sum_{n = 1}^{j - 1} K_n(u_n - u_j) -K_j \sum_{l>0} (u_j - u_{j + l}),
$$
but this does not seem right because later I need to find a dispersion relation and it looks like it will depend on $j$.

To simplify thing, let's assume periodic boundary conditions $u_{N +1} = u_1$